# Div's Open/Close with FadeIn Effects

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquerynew.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".home").click(function(event) {
                $(".hout").slideToggle("slow");     
            });
            $(".javascript").click(function(event) {
                $(".jout").slideToggle("slow");
            }); 
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        .menu { margin:0px auto; border:1px solid lightgray; height:30px; width:1000px;background:#FFF;} 
         #page-content { margin:0px auto; width:1000px; border:1px solid green; margin-top:4px; background:#FFF; overflow:auto; height:500px; }
        .home {padding-left:19px;padding-right:29px;padding-top:2px;float:left;border-right:1px solid lightgray;}
        .javascript { padding-left:19px; padding-right:29px; padding-top:2px; float:left; border-right:1px solid lightgray;  }
        .jout { display:none; padding:20px; }
        .hout { display:none; padding:20px; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="home">Home</div>
        <div class="javascript">Javascript</div>
        <div style="padding-left:19px;padding-right:29px;padding-top:2px;float:left;border-right:1px solid lightgray;">jQuery</div>
        <div style="padding-left:19px;padding-right:29px;padding-top:2px;float:left;border-right:1px solid lightgray;">AJAX</div>
        <div style="padding-left:19px;padding-right:29px;padding-top:2px;float:left;border-right:1px solid lightgray;">jQuery + PHP</div>
        <div style="padding-left:19px;padding-right:29px;padding-top:2px;float:left;border-right:1px solid lightgray;">AJAX+ PHP</div>
        <div style="padding-left:19px;padding-right:29px;padding-top:2px;float:left;border-right:1px solid lightgray;">jQuery + AJAX + PHP</div>    
    </div>  

    <div class="hout"> Home Content goes here</div>
    <div class="jout"> Javascript Content goes here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have Home | Javascript | jQuery | AJAX etc.,

I need my code to work like:

- when I click home, "hout" div should open with fadeIn effect
- when I click javascript, "jout" div should open with fadeIn effect
  and "hout" div should close.
- when I click jQuery, "jqout" div be opened and previous opened div be closed.

I couldn't get the code to hide/close the previously opened div's. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a div around the content like so

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="hout"> Home Content goes here</div>
    <div class="jout"> Javascript Content goes here</div>
</div>
```

**So that it is becomes generic and you don't have to call a particular div to hide again and again, like `$(".hout").hide()` when clicking on `.javascript`. This will work even when you add some other content without having to specifically tell a particular div to hide.**

And jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#content').children().hide(); 

    $(".home").click(function(event)
    {
        $('#content').children().not('.hout').hide();  
        //children() will get all the div inside content ... .not('.hout') will exculde the `div` which you have to slideToggle.. so that it won't hide.. and slideToggle works as it should
        $(".hout").slideToggle("slow");      
    });

    $(".javascript").click(function(event)
    {
        $('#content').children().not('.jout').hide(); 
        $(".jout").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGmYv/6/)

Comment: Hi bipen, thank you for your help, cuould you explain what $('#content').children().not('.hout').hide(); 
      $(".hout").slideToggle("slow"); these lines do when i click home

Comment: updated.. added comment check it out.. naywas welcome... happy coding.. glad it helpe.. let me know if any poblem

Comment: Hi bipen, can the home content be the default one as the page lands

Comment: yes instead of `$('#content').children().hide(); `   in second line replace with...`$('#content').children().not('.hout').hide();`

Answer (score 1):

See **[this example](http://jsfiddle.net/j7Vbd/3/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu div").click(function (event) {
        $(this).parent().siblings(':not([class$=' + this.className + '])').slideUp("slow");
        $(this).parent().siblings('[class$=' + this.className + ']').slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="home">Home</div>
    <div class="javascript">Javascript</div>
    <div class="jquery" style="padding-left:19px;padding-right:29px;padding-top:2px;float:left;border-right:1px solid lightgray;">jQuery</div>
    <div class="ajax" style="padding-left:19px;padding-right:29px;padding-top:2px;float:left;border-right:1px solid lightgray;">AJAX</div>
    <div class="jqphp" style="padding-left:19px;padding-right:29px;padding-top:2px;float:left;border-right:1px solid lightgray;">jQuery + PHP</div>
    <div class="ajphp" style="padding-left:19px;padding-right:29px;padding-top:2px;float:left;border-right:1px solid lightgray;">AJAX+ PHP</div>
    <div class="japhp" style="padding-left:19px;padding-right:29px;padding-top:2px;float:left;border-right:1px solid lightgray;">jQuery + AJAX + PHP</div>
</div>
<div class="a hout-home">Home Content goes here</div>
<div class="a jout-javascript">Javascript Content goes here</div>
<div class="a jout-jquery">jQuery Content goes here</div>
<div class="a jout-ajax">AJAX Content goes here</div>
<div class="a jout-jqphp">jQuery + PHP Content goes here</div>
<div class="a jout-ajphp">AJAX+ PHP Content goes here</div>
<div class="a jout-japhp">jQuery + AJAX + PHP Content goes here</div>
```

Comment: This was perfect and works with all parent and child divs, Thank You for your suggetsion

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this line:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().fadeOut(); // <----hides .hout .jout etc
```

So your code should look like this:

```
$('.home').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().siblings().fadeOut();
    $('.hout').fadeIn();
});

$('.javascript').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().siblings().fadeOut();
    $('.jout').fadeIn();
});
```

#### [CHECKOUT THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZenAJ/1/)